# Binding eventhandlers in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am creating html-elements in a loop, and want to attach event-handlers to some of the elements. This handlers need to know the id of the element that fired the event, so I added the elements id's as a parameter of the binded function, but anyway what element I click at the end, the function always received the id of the last element, not of the element that I clicked.

Here is the code (more simplified version in the next code-block) (I'm using jQuery, but this is not a jQuery-problem, just a JavaScript-problem)

```
receiveObjects = function (JSONobj, StatusString, jqXHR) {
    var html, i, el;

    // error-handling is not shown here

    html  = '<table>';
    for (i = 0; i <  JSONobj.list.length; i++) {
        el = JSONobj.list[i];

        html += '<tr>';

        html += '<td class="td1" id="td1'+el.itemID+'">';
        html +=     '<table>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="up9x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowUp9.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="up3x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowUp3.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="up1x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowUp1.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="down9x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowDown9.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="down3x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowDown3.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=             '<td><img id="down1x'+el.itemID+'" src="pics/arrowDown1.png" alt="" style="width:25px;height:66px;"></td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td colspan="3">';
        html +=                 '<div><button id="delete'+el.itemID+'" name="delete'+el.itemID+'" value="delete'+el.itemID+'">delete</button></div>';
        html +=                 '<div id="saveDiv'+el.itemID+'" style="display:none;">';
        html +=                     '<button id="save'+el.itemID+'" name="save'+el.itemID+'" value="save'+el.itemID+'">save</button>';
        html +=                 '</div>';
        html +=             '</td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=     '</table>';
        html += '</td>';

        html += '<td class="td2" id="td2'+el.itemID+'">';
        html +=     '<table>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td>Titel&nbsp;</td>';
        html +=             '<td>';
        html +=                 '<input class="grau" type="text" id="inTitel'+el.itemID+'" size="30" maxsize="50" value="'+el.Titel+'">';
        html +=             '</td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td>ET</td>';
        html +=             '<td>';
        html +=                 '<input class="grau" type="text" id="inET'+el.itemID+'" size="20" maxsize="30" value="'+el.ET+'">';
        html +=             '</td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=         '<tr>';
        html +=             '<td>Text&nbsp;</td>';
        html +=             '<td>';
        html +=                 '<textarea class="grau" id="inText'+el.itemID+'" rows="4" cols="30">'+el.Text+'</textarea>';
        html +=             '</td>';
        html +=         '</tr>';
        html +=     '</table>';

        html +=     '<button id="loadPdf'+el.itemID+'" name="loadPdf'+el.itemID+'" value="loadPdf'+el.itemID+'">upload pdf</button>';
        html += '</td>';

        html += '<td class="td3" id="td3'+el.itemID+'">';
        html +=     '<img src="'+el.pic+'">';
        html +=     '<div>';
        html +=         '<button id="newPic'+el.itemID+'" name="newPic'+el.itemID+'" value="newPic'+el.itemID+'">create pic from pdf</button> ';
        html +=     '</div>';
        html += '</td>';

        html += '</tr>';

    }

    html += '</table><div class="ErrorMsg" id="changeRedError"></div>';

    $('#workBlock').html(html);

    //after the elements are inserted into the dom, the eventhandlers should be binded:

    for (i = 0; i <  JSONobj.list.length; i++) {
        el = JSONobj.list[i];

        $('#up9x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,-9);})
        $('#up3x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,-3);})
        $('#up1x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,-1);})
        $('#down9x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,9);})
        $('#down3x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,3);})
        $('#down1x'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickMove(el.itemID,1);})

        $('#delete'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickDelete(el.itemID);})

        $('#save'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickSave(el.itemID);})

        $('#inTitel'+el.itemID).on('change keyup paste mouseup',function(){evHd.changed(el.itemID);})
        $('#inET'+el.itemID).on('change keyup paste mouseup',function(){evHd.changed(el.itemID);})
        $('#inText'+el.itemID).on('change keyup paste mouseup',function(){evHd.changed(el.itemID);})

        $('#loadPdf'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickLoadPdf(el.itemID);})

        $('#newPic'+el.itemID).on('click',function(){evHd.clickNewPic(el.itemID);})
    }
}
```

The problem must be located in the way how I attach the id (`el.itemID`) to the event-handler function. Simplified:

```
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    el = JSONobj.list[i];
    $('#prefix'+i).on('click',function(){
        handler(i); //this seems to be problematic
    })
}
```

I think I know where the problem is, but I have no idea how to solve it. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake, due to JavaScript's concept of **closures** (function plus pointers to all the variables outside the function that have been referenced in the function body). You can solve this with an **IIFE** (immediately invoked function expression):

```
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  (function(num) {
    $('#prefix' + num).on('click',function() {
      handler(num);
    })
  })(i);
}
```

This immediately invoked function will create a new scope and thus have the correct `i` saved in `num`. Otherwise, JavaScript's closure (the function keeps a pointer on `i` and thus always references 500 after the `for` loop ended) will mess with your event handlers.